# Position DIV 25px from top of page?

Tags: css, html, position

I have a div that is created as :

```
<div class="test" style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
```

it's horizontal position is fine, but I want to drop is 25px (possibly more) from the top of the page.

I've tried adding `top:25px;` to the style and adding the test class css but it hasn't helped.

```
div.test{
    color:black; 
    text-align:center; 
    border-radius:5px; 
    -moz-border-radius:5px; 
    border:1px solid #FFF; 
    background-color:#434987; 
}
```

I do have another div on the page that is using `position:absolute;` and I can put that where I want... but I can't get that to work with this div when I'm using `margin:0 auto` to align it centrally horizontally..

Can anyone offer some advice how I do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply multiple margin CSS rules:

```
margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 25px
```

`top` (left, right and bottom as well) only work on certain positioned elements (absolute, fixed, static). [**Here**](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/) is a good video about CSS positioning

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFpRN/

Comment: You can use this notation : `margin: 25px auto 0`

Comment: @eskimo Thanks that works well.
@ MTranchany thanks for the shorter version